# Django, all views require login except `@login_not_required` decoratored views

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-middleware

Django is centered towards allow access to all the majority of the time, and restricting acces on the exception.

I am making a site whereby I would like access restricted the most of the time, and the rare case is open to all. Ensuring that one has added a `@login_required` decorate to all views is error prone.

I acheived this by [creating a custom middleware like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377086/set-all-pages-to-require-login-globally). To keep track of open URLs, I defined a list, and then whenever I wished to open up a URL, I added it to the list, and the middleware checked the request path against this list, and allowed exceptions accordingly.

This method above works, but I often mess it up with changing urls, and other issues to do with code reuse on different sites.

Ideally I would like to create my own `@login_not_requied` decorator. How to get the class based view or function the request is going to call within the middleware, so I can check whether the view does not require login?

Answer (score 0):

First create the decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def login_not_required(obj):
    """Adds the attrbiute login_not_required = True to the object (func/class).

    Use it as follows:
        @login_not_required
        class FooView(generic.View):
            ...

        @login_not_required
        def bar_view(request):
            ...
    """
    @wraps(obj)
    def decorator():
        obj.login_not_required = True
        return obj
    return decorator()
```

Then create your own custom middleware:

```
from contextlib import suppress

from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect

NONE_AUTH_ACCOUNT_PATHS = [
    settings.STATIC_URL,
    '/accounts/login/',
    '/accounts/password_reset/',
    '/accounts/reset/',
    '/favicon.ico',
    '/terminal/login/',
    '/terminal/login_failed/',
]


class RequireLoginCheck:
    """Middleware to require authentication on all views by default, except when allowed.

    URLS can be opened by adding them to NONE_AUTH_ACCOUNT_PATHS, or by adding
    the @login_not_required decorator.

    Must appear below the sessions middleware because the sessions middleware
    adds the user to the request, which is used by this middleware.
    """

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def _is_none_auth_path(self, path):
        for none_auth_path in NONE_AUTH_ACCOUNT_PATHS:
            if path.startswith(none_auth_path):
                return True
        return False

    def _is_login_not_required(self, view_func):
        with suppress(AttributeError):
            # If a class with the @login_not_required decorator, will return True
            return view_func.view_class.login_not_required
        with suppress(AttributeError):
            # If a function with the @login_not_required decorator, will return True
            return view_func.login_not_required
        return False

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        """https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/middleware/#other-middleware-hooks"""
        if not (
            request.user.is_authenticated
            or self._is_login_not_required(view_func)
            or self._is_none_auth_path(request.path)
        ):
            if settings.LOGIN_URL != request.path:
                # if next URL after login is the same login URL, then cyclic loop
                return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
            else:
                return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, '/'))
        return None
```

Ensure you add your middleware to `MIDDLEWARE` bellow the sessions middleware, in `settings.py`!
If you have ways it can be improved, please comment below and we make it better for all.